# How to place point information in a .hgt file

Tags: lidar, global-mapper, hgt

I am a noob when it comes to LiDAR data.  I normally work with las, lasx or las tiles to create golf courses from around the world for a game.  I have recently have had a request to create a golf course in France.  Unfortunately, they do not have LiDAR data in the formats I work with above.  The potential customer steered me to a website that provides `.hgt` files for France.

I am able to open these files in Global Mapper, but cannot do anything with them because there is no point data in the file.  How can I work with these files so I can eventually convert them to las/laz format?  If I click on classify Ground button in the las tool withing the app I get the message, `"You must first select at least one lidar point"`.  Obviously there are not points in the file.

Is there a way to work with these files for my purpose?

Comment: Does this help ? https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_ReadersWriters/srtmhgt/srtmhgt.htm . I don't know how to read those file (seems that FME can) but they are DTM not point cloud

Comment: HGT format stores SRTM (Shuttle Radar Topography Mission) digital elevation/surface model (DEM/DSM) data. It's raster data.  You can convert it to point, but is unlikely to be of much use for creating a model of a golf course, it's low resolution (30m or 90m) and is not "bare earth", it includes vegetation and structures and you can't create a ground classification from it.

Comment: Thanks @user2856 I don't know if its me but the link he gave me references 1"? https://data.opendataportal.at/dataset/dtm-france

Comment: 1" = 1 [arc-second](https://www.google.com/search?q=1+arc+second+in+metres), not 1 inch. From your link *The 1 "and 3" models are divided into 1 ° x1 ° file tiles and are in the SRTM format (.hgt) that is widely used and used by numerous software. They have a horizontal resolution of approx. 20x30m (1 ") and approx. 60x90m (3"), as well as a vertical resolution of 1m*